# How to round predictions

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

When I use cross-validation in sklearn, it returns me an RMSE value. The RMSE value is calculated by the root mean square of the predicted y value(for example, 7.11) - the real y value( for example, 6). I want to calculate RMSE by using the root mean square of the rounded predicted y value(for example, round(7.11) = 7) - the real y value(for example, 6). How do I do this? I use python. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: something like      rmse = ((np.rint(model.predict(x_test)) - y_test) ** 2).mean() ** 0.5

Answer (score 2):

In that case you can first round your predicted y value.
To round it to the nearest number you can use np.round(), to round it to the next number you can use np.ceil(), or to round it to. The previous number you can use np.floor().

And then you can calculate your rmse value .

```
y_pred=model.predict(x_test)
y_pred=np.rint(y_pred)
```

Round this value using one of the above methods and then calculate the final rmse value

```
rmse=np.sqrt(np.mean((y_test-y_pred)**2))
```

remember, when you round the values they are not rounded inplace. you have to store them explicitly.